# Displaying Yes or No in a TextBox

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox

My TextBox is displaying 0 or -1 when a button is clicked. The datatype on the table is Short text and there is no default value for both the table field or textbox. I have the TextBox bound to SYC field. I have compacted and repaired, I even created a new field and a new TextBox but all does not seem to work. What could the problem be?

```vb
   Private Sub btnSYC_AfterUpdate()
   If Me.Value = "Yes" Then
        Me.SYC.Value = "No"
    ElseIf Me.SYC.Value = "No" Then
        Me.SYC.Value = "Yes"
    End If
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the Yes/No format is the properties tab?

Comment: The database field is Text but you are using "Yes" and "No" and they are boolean, in Access that means "Yes/No" datatype(No=0 and Yes=-1). So you're VBA is incorrectly interpreting `Me.SYC.Value = "No"` as setting it to the boolean value No, which in text is 0.

Comment: @KostasK. Yes I did! The data-type the textbox doesn't like the words Yes or No and still interprets them as 0 and -1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub btnSYC_AfterUpdate()

    Me!SYC.Value = Not Me!SYC.Value

End Sub
```

and set the *Format* property of the textbox to: *Yes/No*